# My php generated form disappears from the HTML page after a second

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a survey form for recreational activities.  The user is required to input a location which is then searched in a MYSQL database to ensure that the name entered matches the standard names for locations.  The results are to be displayed in a select form to allow the user to choose the specific location.

The query appears to be working correctly.  I have verified the return string via an alert window.  However, the form appears for a brief second then disappears.  I have tried writing the innerHTML string to both a  tag and directly to the form.  Other posts on this topic that I have found indicated that a form tag is not closed properly.  This does not appear to be my problem.

When I run the php script from a test page using hard coded locations, and no other elements on the page, it works just fine.

My js script:

```
<script> function getLoc(){

    var dataRequest;

    try {        
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        dataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {

            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                dataRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {

                try {
                    dataRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {

                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser needs to be updated to run this 
                    application!");
                    return false;
                    }
        }
    }       

    dataRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(dataRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (dataRequest.status==200 || 
                window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
                    document.getElementById("locDropDown").innerHTML = 
                dataRequest.responseText;
            }
            else{
                alert("An error has occured making the request");
            }
        }
    }  
var queryString = "";
queryString = 
  encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('locStr').value.toUpperCase()); 

dataRequest.open("POST", "retrieveLoc.php", true);
dataRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
    urlencoded");
dataRequest.send("searchValue=" + queryString);

}

</script>

<div>
    <form id="floc">
        <strong>Where Did You Go:</strong> <input type="text" id = "locStr" 
        placeholder="location"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="getLoc()">
    </form>
</div>

<!--    <div id="dataDiv"> -->
  <form id="locDropDown">
  </form>
<!--    </div> -->
```

The relevant portion of my php script:

```
<?php

$queryStr = htmlspecialchars($_POST['searchValue']);
$queryStr .= "%";

// Check sql
$locSql = "SELECT location FROM `location_lkup`  \n"
    . "WHERE location LIKE '" .$queryStr. "' \n"  
    . "ORDER BY `location_lkup`.`location` ASC";

$locRslt = $conn->query($locSql);

//Build Result String
/* $display_string = "<form id = 'locDropDown'>"; */
   $display_string .= "<select name = 'locChoices'>";

// If returned records >0 insert a new row in the select form for each loc 
   returned

if ($locRslt -> num_rows > 0) {
$rowcounter = 1;
while($row = $locRslt -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$display_string .= "<option value = " . $rowcounter . ">" . $row['location'] 
. "</option>";
$rowcounter++;
}
}
else {
    $display_string .= "<option value = '1'> NO DATA </option>" ;
}  

$display_string .= "</select>";
$display_string .= "<input type = 'button' value= 'Select' onclick= 
   'getSelectedloc()'>";

 /* $display_string .= "</form>"; */

 echo $display_string;
?>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Put in some `console.log` statements to diagnose what path the javascript is taking. I would assume that `document.getElementById("locDropDown").innerHTML = dataRequest.responseText;` is inserting data that is breaking the HTML.If you can, this would be a lot easier using jQuery. It is a good skill to learn, and would simplify things.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give that a try